# x odd then exists y such that $x^2 = 8y+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I algebraically show that if $x$ is odd, then $x^2 = 8y + 1$?

Making sure it is a true statement, I tabulated some values of $x,y$ pairs
$(1,0)$, $(3,1)$, $(5,3)$, $(7,6)$, $(9,10)$

I let $x = 2w + 1$ (since $x$ is odd)

Then $(2w + 1)^2 = 4w^2 + 4w + 1$

I don't think I can say $4w^2 + 4w + 1 \quad ? \quad 4w + 4w + 1 = 8w + 1$, can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is odd, it is congruent to $\pm 1$ or $\pm 3$ modulo 8. In both cases, its square is congruent to $1$.

Comment: I suppose this works too. Are you missing $\pm 5 \mod 8$?

Comment: I'm missing nothing: $\pm 5\equiv \mp3$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$w^2+w=w(w+1)$$ is divided by $2$,

Comment: Ah! Because either $w$ or $w+1$ is even

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: The missing pieces: $4w^2 + 4w + 1 = (4)(w)(w+1)+1 = 8w + 1$

Comment: @hioqobipb How $(4)(w)(w+1)+1 = 8w + 1$?

Comment: @Ovi From my above comment, $w$ or $w+1$ is even (and thus divible by $2$). I probably shouldn't  use "$=$" since it isn't correct, but I don't know what the correct symbol is

Comment: Why is there so little content in this answer? It came up flagged as a low-quality post, and I was confused looking at it. Did you mean to write more, after that comma?

Answer (score 0):

If $x = 8 k + 1,$ what happens? What if $x=8k + 3?$ You can do the rest.

Comment: What if $x = 3$? Then I can't write $x = 8k$

Comment: If $x=3$, then it is equal to $8k+3$ with $k=0$.